# eloquent query with join and sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

- A: id, total_import, other_columns
- B: id, a_id, partial_import

I want know all rows in A where the sum of `B.partial_import` is less then `A.total_import`.

This is my query:

```
select A.*, sum(B.partial_import) as sum
from A
inner join B on A.id = B.a_id
group by B.a_id
having sum < A.total or sum is null
```

Any suggestions on the best solution to replicate it in eloquent will be appreciated.

Comment: eloquent or query builder?

Comment: Is the same. Query builder is also great

Comment: After receving correct answer you should accept it. You also should not expect full solution for your problem from helping person.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way and also a good way is to use **[query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)**.

If you want to use Collection instead, then you should firsly set [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships), and then to build your eloquent query.

I suppose that your A table has many B rows, so the relation could look like (inside A model):

```
public function B()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\B');
}
```

Then your eloquent will look like:

```
App\A::all()
->B()
->groupBy('B.a_id')
->havingRaw('sum < A.total or sum is null');
```

If you want to use **query builder** your code will look like this:

Firstly at the beginning of your controller use:

```
use DB;
```

And then your query will be something like the following code:

```
DB::table('A')
->join('B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.a_id')
->groupBy('B.a_id')
->havingRaw('sum < A.total or sum is null')
->selectRaw('A.*, sum(B.partial_import) as sum')
->get();
```

Comment: in your example missing the select sum(B.partial_total). with this, I obtain this error:  
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'A.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select A.*, sum(B.partial_import) as sum from A inner join B on A.id = B.a_id group by B.a_id having A.total > sum or sum is null)`

From your query, I've add:  
`->select('A.*', DB::raw('sum(B.partial_import) as sum'))`